# Which one performs better a function or an object in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: jquery, performance, function, object

```
//Object approach
$.myutils = {
    addNumbers : function(a,b){
        //assuming a and b are integers for simplicity
        return a + b;
    }
    subNumbers : function (a,b){
        //assuming a and b are integers for simplicity
        return a - b;
    }
};
//Usage
$.myutils.addNumbers(20,10);
$.myutils.subNumbers(20,10);

//function approach
$.myutils = function()
{
    return {
        addNumbers : _addNumbers,
        subNumbers : _subNumbers
    };
    _addNumbers : function(a,b){
        //assuming a and b are integers for simplicity
        return a + b;
    }
    _subNumbers : function (a,b){
        //assuming a and b are integers for simplicity
        return a - b;
    }   
}
//Usage
$.myutils().addNumbers(20,10);
$.myutils().subNumbers(20,10);
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ to the rescue

Comment: The second example will give a parse error... `_addNumbers : function` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Domenic The second approach won't work as it is, but **the syntax is valid** ;-) `_addNumbers` is a label and `function` is used in a statement context. However, the code `{addNumbers: _addNumbers, ...` will throw a Reference Error exception because `_addNumbers` "is not defined".

Answer (score 2):

While this *could* be considered the case of premature optimization, consider the case that the *semantics are different* and the first method is likely preferred (as there is no additional state stored).

Anyway, the first "objects" method is "faster" (for some value of "faster") because the *same functions* which are properties of *the same object* are invoked.

The second "functions" method will be "slower" (for some value of "slower") because *each time* the `myutils` function is executed (but remember, functions are also objects) it return a *new object* that has *new functions* as properties. Thus, just by definition is has to do more work. (Also, the second method *will not run* as it is, I translated it to "working code" in my head.)

Happy coding.

---

Following zerkms's comment, I have added a jsperf test-case: http://jsperf.com/5931661 (It also includes appropriate bug-fixes; both "examples" were actually broken).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: an object is faster.

Your function returns an object - why would it be faster than a direct object??